# javafx - log in function executes 'else' block if log in details are correct but nothing happens when details are wrong

Tags: javafx

So i have this log in controller that executes the 'else' block when the details are correct, meaning the typed username and password exists in the database. That shouldn't happen. What should happen is that if the details are correct, the 'if' block should be executed and then it goes to another scene and if the details are wrong an alert will pop-up (the content of the 'else' block).

## Log_inController.java

```
public class Log_inController implements Initializable {
private DBConnection dc;

@FXML TextField txtUn;
@FXML PasswordField txtPw;
@FXML Button btnLogin;


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}    


@FXML
public void log_in (ActionEvent event) throws SQLException, IOException {
     dc = new DBConnection();
   try{
        String name =  txtUn.getText();
        String pass =  txtPw.getText();
        
        
        Connection conn = dc.Connect();
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_lib WHERE lib_acc = '"+ name +"'");
   
    
    if(rs.next()){
        String database_name = rs.getString(1);
        String database_pass = rs.getString(2); 
        
        if(name.equals(database_name) && pass.equals(database_pass)){
            Parent x=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Collection_UI/Home.fxml")); 
            Scene  M= new Scene(x);
            Stage app=(Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            app.setScene (M);
            app.show();
        }else{
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setHeaderText("Invalid Credentials");
            alert.setContentText("Please input your valid username and password then try again");

            alert.showAndWait();  
        }
   }
    
}
 catch(SQLException ex){
     System.err.println("Error"+ex);
 }
         
         }
    
}
```

Here is a screenshot when correct details are entered:

https://imgur.com/8k0s7ia

What can be done to fix this and achieve the desired effect? Please.

Comment: @kleopatra i'll keep that in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be in statement.
Try to use PreparedStatement for resolve typical problems with SQL-syntax.

```
PreparedStatement st = conn.createStatement()("SELECT * FROM tbl_lib WHERE lib_acc = ?);
st.setString(1, txtUn.getText());
```

Comment: I reversed the contents of the 'if' block and 'else' block. I worked and would have to do for now. I'll look in prepared statements later on. Thanks. Being a newbie really makes me sweat.